# Determine the limit of a piecewise defined function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> In the piecewise function below, $k$ is a constant.
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^2-k^2}{x-k},&x\neq k,\\ 4-k,&x=k.\end{cases}$$ What is the value of the limit $\lim_{x\to k^-}f(x)$?
>
> 1. $-2k$.
> 2. $2k$.
> 3. $0$.
> 4. Limit does not exist.

[(The above text was originally posted as this image.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN2Lo.png).

I have a question from a released exam that I don't understand. I know the answer which is $2k$ but then I don't understand how to get the answer. It would be great if someone could explain it.

Comment: Please type up the question instead of asking people to click through.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** Link only questions invite down votes and close votes. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please don't post images when you can easily type the material, as here.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand about the question?

Comment: I don't understand how the answer is 2k

Comment: Hint.  $(x + k)(x - k) = x^2 - k^2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Cancelling out the numerator and denominator in the first equation, you get $x+k$ when x does not equal to k.

You are also approaching k from the left.

Hope that helps